# Rails 6 server started by localhost refused to connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, ruby-on-rails-6

This is the message i have in the terminal.

```
~/my-appV2$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.1.4.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 5.5.2 (ruby 3.0.2-p107) ("Zawgyi")
*  Min threads: 5
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: development
*          PID: 5272
* Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3000
* Listening on http://[::1]:3000 Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

However, if i tried to open localhost, i see this:

```
127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
```

I've tried to debug this by going into my /etc/hosts file but to no avail.
Would appreciate if I can get any advice on this!

To further elaborate, I've tried to open other projects on localhost to check if there is an issue with my firewall, and it worked. So I concluded that something is wrong with this specific setup I have here in this particular rails project. For context, Im running Ruby on Rails in Linux, Ubuntu 20.04

Update: I restarted my computer and now, it works...

Comment: What happens if you use this command instead: "rails s -b 0.0.0.0"?

Comment: Passing specific address like "rails s -b 0.0.0.0" should work, or you can try passing a different port "rails s -p 3001"